# Chart.register is not a function (vue-chartjs official example not working)

Tags: vue.js, charts, nuxt.js, vue-chartjs

I am trying to use the official 'vue-charts.js' documentation example into my nuxt 2 project:

```
<template>
  <Bar
    id="my-chart-id"
    :options="chartOptions"
    :data="chartData"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)

export default {
  name: 'BarChart',
  components: { Bar },
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: {
        labels: [ 'January', 'February', 'March' ],
        datasets: [ { data: [40, 20, 12] } ]
      },
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But i get `chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.Chart.register is not a function` error. What Can i be doing wrong?

Additional info:

"nuxt": "^2.15.7",
"vue-chartjs": "^5.2.0",
"chart.js": "^4.2.1"

Comment: Can you include a codepen/jsfiddle/codesandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to **not** rename Chart to ChartJS.
If you get an error regarding module parse failing, you need to use babel-loader to transpile vue-chartjs and chartjs

Mostly due to older webpack version that can't understand modern syntax.

https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/1002

Comment: This fixed the issue. The problem was related to webpack version and could be fixed using nuxt transpilation feature

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you **don't** rename Chart to ChartJS? So, instead, have

```
import { Chart, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js';
Chart.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale);
```

Comment: ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-chartjs/dist/index.js   friendly-errors 12:42:19

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (198:37)        friendly-errors 12:42:19
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders